# Changing letter by number + onkeypress + JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a website to be viewed on a mobile device Nokia C2-01, 240 x 320 pixel resolution, is a single entry form numbers and cell characteristics of the "2" key first digital me the letter "a" then the "b" and "c", the same happens with the "3", I would like to find a solution through Javascript.

Enter the letter "a" and automatically change the number "1"

In

```
a   -> 1
1b  -> 11
11d -> 112
```

and continuous writing...

thanks for the support.

Comment: Please correct your punctuation to make your question more clear. Commas are not a universal device.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you want. Try to explain better (check the structure of your sentences) and perhaps use examples. Also, make sure you add the code you've written to solve the problem and try to explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Create an sample example to understand.

Comment: press letter "a" and converter to "1", automatically convert without losing focus

Comment: And for "g", "h", "i" the numer's output is 3?? @AlberthHinostrozaR.

Comment: yes @MirkoCianfarani is a old phone :(

Comment: I forgot, please do not use jquery, just Native Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood the problem entirely, but if you just want to convert the letters into numbers as they are entered, you can try something like this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/6M3Uu/)

The main transformation 'logic'(if you can call it that) is the line

```
Math.ceil(char.charCodeAt()/3)-32
```

This replaces a/b/c by 1, d/e/f by 2, g/h/i by 3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple exercise.

For example there is a `textarea` that this is controlled from Javascript.

When you push the letter inside the `textarea` this take the letter and convert in number.

How to convert? Simpler convert the letter in code [Asci](http://www.oppo.it/tabelle/img/ascii.gif) and this is subtracted 96.

I add the regex 
`var re = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;`

because this function has to function only for letter.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/EXH2k/42/)

P.s. Excuse for my English if you not understand

Comment: bad my english xD...

if i write "a" or "b" or "c" automatic change to "1", please help me.
and when i write in your DEMO the letter "v" this change to "22" :D

Comment: Only "a","b" and "c" and not other letter??

Comment: I forgot, please do not use jquery, just Native Javascript. tnx